# Polly and Multiple HttpClients

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I want to use Polly in conjunction with my HttpClientFactory (in my C# .NET 5.0 project).

But the problem I have is that I have multiple named HttpClients in my factory and what I am trying to achieve is when I have a specific status code e.g. 404 I want to retry by using *another* named HttpClient from my factory (that points to a different server).

But I see people using the `services.AddHttpClient(name, configureOptions).AddPolicyHandler()` pattern a lot. But that won't work, because that won't call into another named HttpClient.

Also I want to retry both clients "for them selves" when a 408 happens.

Are there any patterns or example code for this?
I don't know what the best way forward is.

Comment: That... doesn't make a lot of sense. You want a library made specifically for retrying an operation to execute an entirely different operation when it fails. You most likely need to do this manually, and abstracting this too much would probably confuse people. Or perhaps your problem is another altogether and this is just the Y of an XY problem?

Comment: @frankhommers You want to have a `ClientA` which will retry in case of `408`. You want to have a `ClientB` which will retry in case of `408`. And if `ClientA` receives `404` then switch to `ClientB`. Is my understanding correct? How does `ClientA` and `ClientB` differs from each other? Do they have different addresses or there is more than that.

Comment: Yes @PeterCsala that's exactly what I am searching for. In the factory I add specific authentication headers and timeouts for ClientA and ClientB.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Well it's not an entirely different operation. It's the same operation but with different headers, addresses and timeouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve the desired the behaviour in the following way.

Let's register two named http client with retry in case of 408 status code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient("ServiceA")
        .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy("ServiceA"));

    services.AddHttpClient("ServiceB")
        .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy("ServiceB"));

    //...
}

private IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy(string name)
    => Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .HandleResult(res => res.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200),
    onRetryAsync: (dr, ts) => { Console.WriteLine($"Retry by {name}"); return Task.CompletedTask; });
```

I've provided an `onRetryAsync` for debugging purposes only to see when does the retry perform.

---

Now let's have a simple webapi controller to wireup things:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory clientFactory;
    public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int expectedStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await GetAsync(GetPrimaryProxy(), expectedStatusCode);
        if(result != null && result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            result = await GetAsync(GetSecondaryProxy(), expectedStatusCode);

        return StatusCode(500, result);
    }

    private HttpClient GetPrimaryProxy() => clientFactory.CreateClient("ServiceA");
    private HttpClient GetSecondaryProxy() => clientFactory.CreateClient("ServiceB");

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(HttpClient client, int expectedStatusCode)
        => await client.GetAsync($"https://httpstat.us/{expectedStatusCode}");
}
```

- I've used the `https://httpstat.us` website to emulate expected response status code
- Unfortunately you have to do the failover manually. The Fallback policy can't be setup in a way that examines `HttpResponseMessage` and returns an `HttpClient`.

#### `/api/Home/404`

The debug logs:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.LogicalHandler: Information: Start processing HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/404
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/404
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/404
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/404
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 319.9439ms - 404
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response headers after 319.9439ms - 404
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 326.1409ms - 404
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.LogicalHandler: Information: End processing HTTP request after 326.1409ms - 404

info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceB.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/404
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceB.LogicalHandler: Information: Start processing HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/404
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceB.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/404
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceB.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/404
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceB.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 344.5937ms - 404
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceB.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response headers after 344.5937ms - 404
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceB.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 350.932ms - 404
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceB.LogicalHandler: Information: End processing HTTP request after 350.932ms - 404
```

- `ServiceA` issued a request and received 404

  - `Retry` did not trigger since 408 is handled only
- `ServiceB` issued a request and received 404

  - `Retry` did not trigger since 408 is handled only

#### `/api/Home/408`

The debug logs:

```
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.LogicalHandler: Information: Start processing HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 343.5167ms - 408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response headers after 343.5167ms - 408

Retry by ServiceA
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 236.9796ms - 408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response headers after 236.9796ms - 408

Retry by ServiceA
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 207.2602ms - 408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response headers after 207.2602ms - 408

Retry by ServiceA
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Sending HTTP request GET https://httpstat.us/408
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 203.3911ms - 408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response headers after 203.3911ms - 408
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.LogicalHandler: Information: End processing HTTP request after 1618.0826ms - 408
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ServiceA.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 1618.0826ms - 408
```

- `ServiceA` issued a request and received 408

  - `Retry` is triggered after 200 ms delay
- `ServiceA` issued a request and received 408

  - `Retry` is triggered after 200 ms delay
- `ServiceA` issued a request and received 408

  - `Retry` is triggered after 200 ms delay
- `ServiceA` issued a request and received 408

  - `Retry` is not triggered because max retry count is exceeded
- `ServiceB` is not called because status code is 408 not 404

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using the `PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions.AddPolicyHandler` but I used this for inspiration to write my own: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly-Samples/blob/master/PollyDemos/Async/AsyncDemo08_Wrap-Fallback-WaitAndRetry-CircuitBreaker.cs